# Android ListView not being repainted on scroll

Tags: java, android, list, listview, view

This is best described with pictures. Before scrolling in my `ListView`, everything looks fine:

[image]

After scrolling:

[image]

What could be causing this odd behavior? I am testing it on a **Google Nexus** running **Android 4.2.2** and have tried it on the emulator running **Android 3.2** with the same result. In this example I am using a `ListView` with two types of rows, but I get the same result with a standard `ListView` with just one row type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I did not set a background color in my layout XML file... If someone could explain to me why this fixes the problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Adding 
android:background="#000000" to my main layout fixed it, though.

....

Comment: I'm not sure but I think with newer devices they use hardware acceleration for drawing layouts and such. I think this utilizes OpenGL ES and if you have ever written something to draw and move around the screen in 3d, and not draw a background, artifacts like that are left behind. I guess since it's never being told to draw to that part of memory it just leaves whatever is there. And it flickers because of buffering and stuff.  Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense. Your premises are correct, at least, and for Android 4.0 and above, Hardware Acceleration is on by default. I was surprised, though, that I couldn't find this occurrence of this specific problem elsewhere on the Internet. After all, I feel like both not putting a background color and having a listview are not that uncommon. Thanks for the explanation!